# Output "single" friends from Facebook > Campaign site

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

Can anyone help?

I was wondering if the following is possible:

- A campaign site which the user has agreed to connect with Facebook.
- The user sees 2 of his single friends (i.e. not married or in a relationship)
- The user can answer a simple question, and choose one of the 2 single friends.
- Done.

Maybe there is then a post on that person's wall to "finish off" the fun of the campaign.

Is it possible to output this information from Facebook to a site?

Thanks!

/R

Answer (score 0):

You can´t get the relationship status of user friends, only the status of the authorized user. You also can´t get ALL friends of the user with `/me/friends`, but only those who authorized your App too.

So in order to achieve something like this, EVERY user would have to authorize your App and you would have to store the relationship status in your own database. You would only be able to choose from authorized users.

Comment: Luschn if you'd like to help with a freelance gig (I'm based in Sweden) please mail me: rus121@hotmail.com - many thanks. I checked out your site, could use your help :)